# Adding WordPress header and footer to a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, get-headers

I am trying to create a custom form in WordPress. Step 1 of the form is HTML code that collects data and sends it to a PHP file through the post method, then writes it to the MySQL database and creates Step 2 of the form using PHP code. My problem is that I want to include the default WordPress header and footer in Step 2 of the form that WordPress uses in Step 1. Is there a way to do this by including the code of header.php and footer.php in my PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

And for the footer:

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If you take a look at the `get_header() function`:

```
 function get_header( $name = null ) {
        /**
         * Fires before the header template file is loaded.
         *
         * The hook allows a specific header template file to be used in place of the
         * default header template file. If your file is called header-new.php,
         * you would specify the filename in the hook as get_header( 'new' ).
         *
         * @since 2.1.0
         * @since 2.8.0 $name parameter added.
         *
         * @param string $name Name of the specific header file to use.
         */
        do_action( 'get_header', $name );

        $templates = array();
        $name = (string) $name;
        if ( '' !== $name ) {
                $templates[] = "header-{$name}.php";
        }

        $templates[] = 'header.php';

        locate_template( $templates, true );
}
```

Do you have at least a header.php file on your root theme?

A common Wordpress structure:

```
your_project_folder
    -wp-admin
    -wp-content
        -languages
        -plugins
        -themes
            -YOUR_THEME_FOLDER
                -[HERE YOU PLACE YOUR index.php file and header.php for example, and inside index.php you place your get_header() function]
        -upgrade
        -uploads
    -wp-includes
    index.php
    wp-activate.php
    wp-blog-header.php
    wp-comments-post.php
    wp-config.php
    wp-cron.php
    [...more files]
```

Comment: I am trying that with the following code:
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php // Script 3.5 - handle_form.php #3 
  
 ini_set('display_errors', 1); // Let me learn from my mistakes! 
 error_reporting(E_ALL); // Show all possible problems! 
  

  
 // Create shorthand versions of the variables: 
 $age = $_POST['age']; 
 $sex = $_POST['sex']; 
 $supplement_user = $_POST['supplement_user']; 
 
  
 // Print the received data: 
 print "<p>Thank you for your form.</p> 
 <p>You stated that you are $age years old and $supplement_user use supplements.</p>"; 
  
 ?>

Comment: This is the error I get: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/whatsu13/public_html/whatsuppnews.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/handle_form.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/whatsu13/public_html/whatsuppnews.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/handle_form.php on line 2

Comment: Why do I get this 'undefined function get_header()' error?

Comment: When you reference a function like get_header(), is there a particular directory you need to be in for Wordpress to recognize the function call?

Comment: Inside your theme http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/

Comment: Are you trying to run a Wordpress theme outside of an installation of Wordpress?

Comment: My php file is located here:  `public_html/whatsuppnews.com/wp-content/themes/Avada` and Avada is the theme I am using, so this seems like the correct place. The php does execute without the **<?php get_header(); ?>**, but when I add that function, it errors.

Comment: It is running on Wordpress

Comment: <?php get_header(); ?>    This is at the top of my php script in the following directory: **public_html/whatsuppnews.com/wp-content/themes/Avada**

Comment: Look at the updated answer. You need at least a header.php file.

Comment: header.php is located in the same directory as my php script: **public_html/whatsuppnews.com/wp-content/themes/Avada**

Comment: I don't know where to help you. Can you check if you have the functions in /wordpress/wp-includes/general-template.php?

Comment: yes, but I have 2 wp-includes, one right under public_html and one under my sitename. Both wp-includes folders have a functions.php file and general-template.php file.

Comment: You need only the one inside WordPress directory not your theme root

Comment: Technically, this is the correct answer. It sounds like you have problems with your Wordpress installation if your theme template file cannot find the function `get_header()`.

Comment: I've just noticed your path... should you have `whatsuppnews.com` inside your `public_html` directory...? If you have two `wp-includes` folders, then I think you have actually put two installations into the same folder. Inside your `public_html` folder should only have three folders: `wp-admin`, `wp-content` and `wp-includes` This is your Wordpress installation.

Comment: Copy everything inside your `whatsuppnews.com` folder, and paste inside your `public_html` folder, then delete your `whatsuppnews.com` folder. That should sort your Wordpress installation back to how it should be. Back up first!

Comment: Ok, I did that. The website is still operational. Inside of public_htlml, I have 4 folders:  wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes and cgi-bin. I have tried running the php file with this command -  wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes, and cgi-bin. I have created my php file with this code: <?php get_footer(); ?>   Then I have put that php file inside of public_html folder and I get the undefined function error. I also put the php file inside the theme folder and I still get an undefined function error.

Comment: Ignore the above comment.

Comment: Ok, I did that. The website is still operational. Inside of public_htlml, I have 4 folders: wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes and cgi-bin. I created a php file with this command: <?php get_footer(); ?>   Then I have put that php file inside of public_html folder and I get the undefined function error. I also put the php file inside the theme folder and I still get an undefined function error.

Comment: I updated my answer again, please @StephenRose read carefully the wordpress documentation, this is so easy to solve and we are creating a big conversation in the comments section. If you need, download wordpress again, start a clean installation and check inside themes/ directory the built-in templates of wordpress and check the correct project structure and the correct use of get_header() function